# Detect SCSI signals using netlink sockets

Tags: kernel, scsi

I'm trying to detect any SCSI signals sent from the kernel using netlink.

Usually I would use udev hooks but I'm trying to detect the addition or removal of hard drives from a RAID controller and udev is not detecting any signals; it seems that the RAID controller is intercepting them.

I'm not sure if detecting signals using netlink will work or if the RAID controller will intercept the signals before netlink can detect them too.

How can I use netlink to detect any SCSI signals and notify a user-space program?